# Unexpected 'undefined offset' error in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, explode

In this project I am sifting through non formatted HTML code and looking for a specific value, below is a section of code from a paragraph deconstruction function.  I am using preg_replace to get rid of any unneeded html code until I end up with a small array of variables delimited by the html 
 tag.  Below is the section of logic I am having a problem with.  For some reason I am receiving an un-defined offset 5 error when attempting to print the 5th position of the array $pieces.  I am using the explode function to create the array and have included the chunk of html code I am running explode on.

```
$new_broken_var = preg_replace($para_search, $para_replace, $para_subject);
$pieces = explode("<br>", $new_broken_var);
echo $pieces[5];

//upon echoing $new_broke_var I received the below html as it's value           
//<font face="Arial" size="2">For 06/01/13 to 06/30/13<br>
//Report Generated: Thursday, July 11,   2013<br>Unit:   204&nbsp;<br>
//Driver:<br>Owner:<br>Number of Trips: 27<br>Fuel Type:   Diesel</font>


   //creates an array using <br> as it's delimiter on the commented code above
   //the variable we want is in position number 5 within the array. and confirmed via print_f($pieces);
```

Comment: The fifth position is offset 4: arrays are indexed from 0, not from 1

Comment: This means that your resulting array does not have six elements. With the `5` you try to access the sixth position because the count starts at 0.

Comment: **Programming 101**: *Offsets start at `[0]` unless mentioned otherwise!*

Comment: `print_r($pieces);` would tell you why.

Comment: sadly I can not seem to echo ANY of the array values with a simple echo command. As I am only interested in a specific value.

Comment: the print_r($pieces); returns with a bunch of the array variables.
[5] => Unit: 204   (and reveals it is holding the value I need)

Comment: Array ( [0] =>

[1] => [2] => For 06/01/13 to 06/30/13 [3] => Report Generated: Thursday, July 11, 2013 [4] => NATIONAL FOOD CORPORATION [5] => Unit: 204  [6] => Driver: [7] => Owner: [8] => Number of Trips: 27 [9] => Fuel Type: Diesel
) Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] =>

) Array ( [0] =>

) 

I believe something weird is happening with my explode function as I am getting a few extra empty arrays

Comment: I fixed the problems of additional arrays by skipping over the empty arrays with an if statement.
`code`
$explode_counter_result = count($pieces);

if($explode_counter_result != 1)
{
echo $pieces[5].'<br'>;
}

I know this isn't the greatest method of fixing it.. but, I'm getting down to the wire and this will have to do.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good practice to check whether the requested index actually exists in your array.

```
if (isset($pieces[5])) {
    echo $pieces[5];
}
```

The index may not exist for various reasons, but in your case it just seems your paragraph is empty, causing `explode()` to return an array with a single element.